# How can i take two date pickers and sort data with my start and end date but json data containsis 5/12/2016 while angular sorts only 05/12/2016?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, datepicker

My json data contains like this

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "city": "Neftegorsk",
    "start_date": "4/13/2013",
    "end_date": "5/18/2013",
    "price": "55.82",
    "status": "Seldom",
    "color": "#fd4e19"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "city": "Lancai",
    "start_date": "5/19/2012",
    "end_date": "11/29/2014",
    "price": "22.49",
    "status": "Yearly",
    "color": "#ff5055"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "city": "Hekou",
    "start_date": "8/28/2011",
    "end_date": "4/7/2014",
    "price": "9.48",
    "status": "Often",
    "color": "#903761"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "city": "Ballymahon",
    "start_date": "8/19/2013",
    "end_date": "8/3/2015",
    "price": "47.53",
    "status": "Often",
    "color": "#cd387d"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "city": "Wesoła",
    "start_date": "3/7/2015",
    "end_date": "4/3/2014",
    "price": "46.66",
    "status": "Never",
    "color": "#e6eeb9"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "city": "New Sibonga",
    "start_date": "6/26/2011",
    "end_date": "1/18/2015",
    "price": "66.36",
    "status": "Often",
    "color": "#bcb97e"
}]
```

it's too complicated to format it in controller or any other suggestion is most welcome

Comment: Welcome to SO. To increase your chances to have an answer, I recommend you to make your question understandable. This starts with properly formatting it which is not the case here.

Comment: sir would you please share me the link where can i format according to website requirements

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript `Array::sort` method takes a function parameter that can be used to sort as you want.

You'll want to turn the strings into proper date objects, then compare those objects.

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

You'll also need

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse